# search and display results

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps, csv

I'm looking to improve my basic code skills and need help with direction on having a search bar that would search a xml or csv file and display a list by close distance to their search. They would enter a city or zip code than the result would list the closest to their search. Also like to add a google map mashup that works with it or maybe by geolocation. Any help with advice and direction would be great.

Here is example of what I looking for http://www.findapainter.com/

Comment: First you need to improve your googling skills.

Answer (score 1):

I always use a combination of this example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp jquery ui autocoplete with geolocation it has a list of countries cities and towns veryyyyyy useful and easy to implement

**Update**

Looking at your link that website find a painter is using exactly the same thing :) jquery autocomplete :)

Comment: that is perfect! how would you get it to list the output of business from a xml or csv file in order of distance from the input search like the sample website?

Comment: probably use the google maps, by listing them as items... here is a link not sure would help you though but good to give it a shot http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html